# Parse data from a website

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I am trying to scrap data for personal use from trustpilot co uk. I parse the name of the websites from this [page](http://www.trustpilot.co.uk/categories/computer). The result I get is:

`2. Flashbay
            ,&,;`

What I want to get is just the name of the website, e.g. "Flashbay".
I use this command `$('.items h3 a')` so far.

Any advice/help of how to accomplish my goal is really appreciated.

Comment: I would expect you'd get `2. Flashbay`. Where does `,&,;` come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var websites = [];
$.each($('.item h3 a'), function () {
    websites.push($(this).text().trim().replace(/^[^A-Z]+/i, ''));
});
console.log(websites);
```

This gave me the following:

```
["Mr Memory", "GoGoDigital", "Maxram", "Quiet PC.com", "Sell Your-laptop",
 "Wiziwoo Ltd", "OFFTEK", "Memoryc", "Total Computing", "ZiiP GameStore",
 "Comms Express", "MicroDream Limited", "Xytron", "Kikatek", "Gizzmo Heaven",
 "Arbico Computers", "Network Webcams", "ShopTo.Net", "PC Specialist Ltd", "rpm"]
```

Comment: @Stefanos.Ioannou You're welcome! Glad that I was able help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use .substring(3,8) on the string variable containing "2. Flashbay ,&,;"

Answer (score 0):

Using substrings as Damien suggested is probably the simplest route. However, using static indices like that wouldn't work, since the strings you're looking at are of variable length, including the leading text to be trimmed off. Looking at the page, here's what works for me:

```
var companies = [];
var elements = $('.items h3 a');
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length;i++){
    var text = $.trim($(elements[i]).text());
    text = text.substr(text.indexOf(".") + 2);
    companies.push(text);
}
console.log(companies);
```

I've tested that on the page you linked to and it seems to work fine. I don't know where that `,&,;` you were getting on the end was coming from.